# Prometheus scraping logs from another prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I have prometheus installed in a kubernetes cluster which should do remote_write to another prometheus. The second prometheus does a remote read. Tell me how to set it up correctly.

prometheus.yml in kubernetes:

```
remote_write:
- url: http://192.168.0.103:9090/receive
  remote_timeout: 30s
  queue_config:
    capacity: 2500
    max_shards: 200
    min_shards: 1
    max_samples_per_send: 500
    batch_send_deadline: 5s
    min_backoff: 30ms
    max_backoff: 100ms
  metadata_config:
    send: true
    send_interval: 1m
```

Prometheus.yml in another machine(reader)

```
remote_read:
- url: https://prometheus.example.com/receive
  remote_timeout: 1m
```

Comment: Please advice if above mentioned configuration is working properly. If it is not working properly, then please provide the prometheus logs

Also, please advice why you are writing from Kubernetes Prometheus to Non Kubernetes Prometheus. Ideally, you should write from Kubernetes Prometheus to Influx DB for Storage and then you can use Monitoring Tools like Grafana, Zabbix, etc. to fetch data from the Influx DB and visualize it or send alerts.